# I’m trying to run a flask on Heroku but I get blocked using gunicorn and waitress

Tags: heroku, gunicorn, reddit, waitress

I’m creating a website to schedule reddit posts and I’ve been stuck on the same error message for hours. I’m using heroku on the web side, but I keep getting an error message, I think the issue might be with my Procfile but I’m not sure how to fix it. The general file is a file titled My reddit scheduler. Within this file is the folder *pycache* containing reddit_scheduler.cpython-310.pyc. Within My reddit scheduler is also a folder titled templates containing a file titled index.html. Within My reddit scheduler are also the following files: app.py, Aptfile, Procfile, reddit_scheduler.py, and requirements.txt. The procfile contains the following text:" web: gunicorn app:app " I am not sure if this is correct. I’ve tried different variations but I keep getting the following error:

2023-04-20T16:15:35.296580+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn reddit_scheduler:app`
2023-04-20T16:15:37.569652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2023-04-20T16:15:37.608728+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-04-20T16:15:37.437823+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: line 1: gunicorn: command not found

After trying to figure out how to get around this for a while, I tried using waitress instead, with the procfile reading: web: waitress-serve —port=$PORT reddit_scheduler:app
I got essentially the same response when I tried to push to deployment.
2023-04-21T03:55:07.355718+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-04-21T03:55:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-04-21T03:55:12.094271+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `waitress-serve --port=13890 reddit_scheduler:app`
2023-04-21T03:55:12.683646+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: line 1: waitress-serve: command not found
2023-04-21T03:55:12.824744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2023-04-21T03:55:12.865817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
I’m not sure what to do. I’ve added these both to the requirements.txt file, but nothing I do fixes the issue.

Comment: Do you also have a `Pipfile`?